# HTML/JS publish LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, web, publishing

I want to publish an app created with libGDX (HTML/JS publishing). Here are the steps I am doing.
**Right Click on the Project -> Google -> Gwt Compile -> Compile.**
After the compilation there is no .html file in the /war directory . There are 3 folders assets,html,WEB-INF . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Relevant: [WAR (File format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_%28file_format%29)

Comment: ok and how can I run it?

Comment: Do you have a .war file? If yes, you will need a web server that can run it (mainly a java server, like [Apache Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat)). Have you tried looking for other compile target options? Maybe you can have something else than a .war.

Comment: no I don`t have .war file , I have a folder named war and it has 3 subfolders assets,html,WEB-INF

Comment: @AlexandreDesbiens the requirements of a web server for HTML/JS deployment of a libGDX project depends on whether or not server-side operations are being used in the code. See [Deploying to HTML/JS](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Deploying-your-application#deploy-to-htmljs) for more information.

Comment: no I don't have any server-side operations , but they say after GWT compile I can launch with index.html but I don`t have index.html ini my \war directory

Answer (score -1):

On Android Studio, on the heeader menu go to:
View->Tool Windows->Gradle

There you will see all you subprojects.
open up the 'other', right click on the task 'dist' and click 'run'.

This will create the distribution file in your HTML->build->dist folder.
You can copy those file to your root folder (or link your root folder to this location)

Comment: He never said he uses android studio